# connection beetwen html, js and cocoa by webkit

Tags: javascript, html, cocoa, webkit

i have cocoa app with embed webkit, which show simple html with
`<input id="first_name" type="text">` and `<input id="start" type="button">`

and i want this: when you click `#start` button, show up a regular cocoa NSAlert with `#first_name` value.
Well, i need to somehow organize a connection between html,js and cocoa.

it it possible?

Comment: May I ask why? Why don't you use Cocoa inputs and buttons without webkit?

Comment: i have a web app with many many complicated forms. now i need to use these forms in cocoa application. and i want just show them in webkit, instead of remake them in Interface Builder.But i also need to interact between these forms and cocoa app. So, that's why i'm asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

it turns out that it's possible:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

working example:
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/CallJS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004241